# Why aren't the vectors carrying over into an other function?

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine, vector

when I assign vectors to the array, the will not be carried over to the rocketUpdate function. The Gene array that is being used comes from an other script running on the gameObjects from the rocket array. This is the script it is from.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Rockets : MonoBehaviour {

    public Vector2[] Gene;

    public void Start()
    {
        Gene = new Vector2[10];
    }
}
```

this is the main "controller" script.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class RocketController : MonoBehaviour {

    public int XVelocityMultiplier;
    public int YVelocityMultiplier;

    int lifespanSec;

    int Count;

    public int Size;
    public GameObject[] rockets;
    public GameObject RocketPrefab;

    public System.Random rnd = new System.Random();
    float x;
    float y;

    void Start()
    {
        rockets = new GameObject[Size];

        lifespanSec = RocketPrefab.GetComponent<Rockets>().Gene.Length;

        Invoke("killRockets", lifespanSec);

        for (int i = 0; i < rockets.Length; i++)
        {
            GameObject rocketObject = Instantiate(RocketPrefab);
            rocketObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().position = new Vector3(0, -4, 30);
            rocketObject.name = "Rocket_" + (i+1);

            for (int j = 0; j < rocketObject.GetComponent<Rockets>().Gene.Length; j++)
            {
                x = Convert.ToSingle(rnd.NextDouble() * (2 * XVelocityMultiplier) + XVelocityMultiplier * (rnd.Next(-1,1) + 0.1f));
                y = Convert.ToSingle(rnd.NextDouble() * (YVelocityMultiplier));
                rocketObject.GetComponent<Rockets>().Gene[j] = new Vector2(x, y);
                Debug.Log(rocketObject.GetComponent<Rockets>().Gene[j]);
            }
            rockets[i] = rocketObject;

        }
        InvokeRepeating("RocketUpdate", 0, 1);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Count == lifespanSec)
        {
            Count = 0;
        }
    }

    void RocketUpdate()
    {
        Debug.Log(rockets[1].GetComponent<Rockets>().Gene[Count]);
        if (rockets[0] != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < rockets.Length; i++)
            {
                rockets[i].GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = rockets[i].GetComponent<Rockets>().Gene[Count];
            }
            Debug.Log(rockets[1].GetComponent<Rockets>().Gene[Count]);
        }
        Debug.Log(Count);
        Count++;
    }

    void killRockets()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < rockets.Length; i++)
        {
            Destroy(rockets[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

when I run the first Debug.log() in the start function, every gameObject has its values. but when I run the same Debug.log in rocketUpdate() it suddenly doesn't have its values anymore. I have been stuck on the same problem for a long time. if anyone knows the problem please do tell.

Comment: A sidenote: in general try to avoid to call `GetComponent` over and over again. Instead store and reuse the reference once you got it the first time. You could e.g. already make the `rockets` of type `Rockets[]` or why not using `List<Rocket>()`? The huge advantage of lists is that you can extend them on the fly.

Comment: Culd you explain a bit further what your entire code is supposed to do exactly .. I'm still trying to figure out everything that's supposed to happen here

Comment: I was going to create an AI. but first I needed to create the script that just runs through an array of vectors and sets the rigidbodies to those vectors

Answer (score 0):

Several things. In your first script you aren't populating an array with a bunch of values, you are creating a new array with space for 10 Vector2s. I'm not sure if that's what you want, but it's what it is. In order to populate it with data, you have to explicitly tell it what the data should be by creating a reference to the script holding the actual values. For example,

```
private MainScript whateverYouWannaCallIt;
private Vector2[] geneCopies; 

public void Awake()
{
    whateverYouWannaCallIt = gameObject.GetComponent<MainScript>();

    for (int i = 0; i < whateverYouWannaCallIt.rockets.Length; i++)
    {
        geneCopies[i] = whateverYouWannaCallIt.rockets.gene[i];
    }
}
```

You should also initialize a List and populate it with those rockets and maybe one for the rigidbodies as well, those getComponent calls are gonna contribute a lot to your overhead.

Also, I'm intrigued. What is your goal with this script? And what's your game about?

Comment: I was going to create an AI. but I am running into a lot of roadblocks so it isn't running very smoothly. in your code the first line, my c# script doesn't recognize the type MainScript. do I have to generate a new type? or can I use the type Component

Comment: `In your first script you aren't populating an array with a bunch of values, you are creating a new array with space for 10 Vector2s.` .. as far as I can see the array is filled with `rocketObject.GetComponent<Rockets>().Gene[j] = new Vector2(x, y);`. I also see no `MainScript` in the question. `You should also initialize a List and populate it with those rockets` .. isn't this what the `public GameObject[] rockets;` is for?

Comment: He has a  small snippet from an auxiliary script at the top called rockets and a larger main script below it called rocketController. In the first script there is only the creation of an array, nothing else. You are right about the rockets array though, but he should still use another array for each rocket's rigidbody to avoid those getcomponent calls every second @derHugo

Comment: Yeah you need to rename all these things to match your variable names, and where I say MainScript, you need to name it exactly what your class is named otherwise it will not be able to find it.

Comment: and it's not every second but every frame ;)

Comment: You are calling RocketUpdate via InvokeReapeating, the second parameter of which is the interval time. You set it at one, so it runs once every second. If you want it to update every frame, just call the method in update and save yourself some overhead from that Invoke. But if you do that, you really should not be calling GetComponent every frame. Hope this all helps!